# Python - Teamspeak3 Library

Tags: library, python

I'm searching for a Python lib where I can run a standalone Teamspeak3 client and connect for example to a random server and respond on chat messages without have permissions for the server query, ssh, telnet etc.

I know Java has the possibility to do something like that, for example [ts3j](https://github.com/Manevolent/ts3j).

So I searched for a package in Python but I did not find anything that is representing that.

I hope someone can help me here or show me an alternative where I don't need a server query.

What I found so far:

- [PyTS3](https://github.com/benediktschmitt/py-ts3) (only for server query)
- [pyTSon](https://www.myteamspeak.com/addons/86d2c267-1b43-4a4b-8cfb-06c2d8208bdc) (python plugins for ts3)